pelias - how to remove data ingested from csv-importer
currently i have a pelias instance provisioned using pelias-docker.
In order to feed it with custom data i am using csv-importer.
Now i need a way to manage the data ingested (i.e. edit, remove and so on)
So far the solution i've found is to wipe out the docker pelias instance and feed it again with data.
Any guidance is welcome.
